# Blender render issues(in cycles, evee, and viewport render) blends start fine and then this issue appears

Tags: rendering

I am having issues getting blender to consistently render images with the correct colors. I am also doing texture baking and it see4ms issues start to happen after my first texture bake. The view - viewport render option comes out super dark, and the normal render option comes out super bright or white even. If I append the object I am trying to capture to a new blend file the issues go away at first, but always come back after doing a few texture bakes. blend file with images removed is here, still has the same issues
[image]
[image]